# apache on windows not recognizing more than one vhost

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I am attempting to set up a local WAMP server and I am running into a problem with mapping domains to directories. When I just do one directory it works fine, but once I add another it doesn't work. This is what I have in my vhosts file.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<Directory "D:\server ">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>


#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#


NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "d:\server\ctlife"
   ServerName site1.local
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   DocumentRoot "d:\server\phpmyadmin"
   ServerName site2.local
</VirtualHost>
```

And then in my hosts file I have put in this

```
127.0.0.1 site1.local
127.0.0.1 site2.local
```

If i take out site2.local in both files everything works fine, but doesn't seem to recognize the other one. I have followed a bunch of tutes on this and can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have 2 NameVirtualHost, try removing the 2nd one or the 1st and maybe it is conflicting... ALSO you have a space at <Directory "D:\server "> could you try remove it... i know it may not be the problem but might be interfering with apache.

Comment: Did that worked ? by the way what is in your error_log file from apache

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have a full NameVirtualHost statement with IP and port, such as

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
```

I would try that and remove the duplicate/overlapping NameVirtualHost statements.  Also adjust your VirtualHosts to include IP:Port like:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Should do the trick.  Good luck! :)